# Install Linux on External HDD as a secondary OS

Tags: linux

Is it possible to install an OS on the external HDD? If I currently have Windows (7), will it be able to boot Windows/Linux?

2nd question: I tried both Windows 7 on x32 and x64 bit. They were both working. Is there anything like Debian on 64 bit? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible. If you've installed Windows first it should be a breeze with most modern Linux installers.

Debian 64-bit definitely exists and happens to be the OS I use everyday. I do everything from playing Quake to software development.

Also, next time check out [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com) if you have other Unix/Linux questions unrelated to programming.

Comment: a bit of help would be appreciated, which one of these is the 64? amd64 armel kfreebsd -i386 kfreebsd-amd64 i386 ia64 mips mipsel powerpc sparc s390 source multi-arch. I know i386 is good for 32 bit.

Comment: `amd64` is the 64-bit version you're looking for. Just FYI `ia64` is not what you're looking for, that's a different architecture (albeit 64 bits).

Comment: amd64 even though it's an Intel?

Comment: Yes, AMD first came out with a 64-bit x86 architecture, and Intel later followed suit. All modern 64-bit x86 processors use the AMD64 instruction set. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64 for more info if you're curious.

Answer (score 2):

yes, with http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ you can install many Linux distributions easily on a external usb drive/stick.

To boot from that external drive, your computer needs to be correctly set up in BIOS. Usually there is a "boot from external/usb" option, that needs to be active and in right order, your USB-drive needs to be bootable also. But just try it out...

ad 2nd) sure I can recommend you UBUNTU it is based on debian http://www.ubuntu.com/download, just take the 64bit edition **amd64**

Answer (score 2):

1st depends on your bios. My Asus Z68VPro can also boot from an USB-Stick or mount the USB-Stick as a virtual harddrive.

2nd Most precompiled kernels in the Debian repository support 64bit.

It sounds, like you are not that deep into linux. Check userfriendly distributions like Ubuntu or Kubuntu which also base on debian and have a really nice UI.